# How to save a workflow service as an App?

Tags: mac, xcode, automator, mac-appstore

I have a workflow service I built using Automator that I would like to distribute through the Mac App Store.

I've successfully "exported" the workflow, signed with my developer ID.  I can open the workflow in XCode, but I don't see options to [set the bundle ID, assign to a team etc](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev91fe7130a).

Any ideas?